# UITextbox and Navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating an iOS app with swift and XCode 6. I have a multiple page app with a navigation controller. So far so good. When I enter text in one of the subpages go back to the front and reenter this page the text is gone.

My question to you is how to edit the code, so that the text stays in the text box and does not disappear. I know to somehow create a database but thats all I found so far.

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you go "back" you essentially pop the `viewcontroller` from the **navigationstack**. At that point there are no more references to that `viewcontroller` and it get's deallocated and as a result you loose all your changes.
So if u want to save your text you can store it in `NSUserDefaults`

```
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(textField.text, forKey:"key")
```

And in `viewDidLoad` of specific `viewController` where you want to populate `UItextField` fetch it like

```
textField.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("key") as! String
```

Comment: Thank you so far. I have one question left: If i put
`textField.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("key") as! String`
in the `viewDidLoad` function the program interupts. Obviously because the first time `"key"` is empty. How can I avoid that?

Comment: add check if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("key") != nil){ textField.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("key") as! String }